# Chrome is changing milliseconds to date in console

Tags: date, milliseconds

I'm trying to give a span element a id from milliseconds.

```
var span_id = new Date();
$('#query').append('<span id="'+span_id+'"></span><br>');
```

When i inspect the span element in the console it shows like this:

```
<span id="Tue Feb 09 2021 11:53:54 GMT+0100 (centraleuropeisk normaltid)"></span>
```

How can i save the time in milliseconds.. so that the span id will be a long number.. like: 1239484738329303

I've tried:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMilliseconds();
```

But this will only give me the milliseconds right now.. separated from the minutes, hours and date.. so it will end up short like: 281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Chrome-only behaviour. Casting a date object to a string (which, by using it as an ID attribute, is what you're doing), well implicitly render it to its full textual representation.

Instead, you need the static `Date.now();`

```
Date.now(); //1612868588100
```